# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Networkprovider> above this Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and was trying out the implementation of Network Connectivity with the Flutter Provider. I got across this error and have tried every bit of code on the Internet from changing the context and changing the place where the Provider might lie so that the child widgets will get the context. When I am trying to get the value of res in welcome. dart I am getting the error.

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

Make sure that Welcome is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately

main.dart

```
void main() {
    runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider(
            create: (context) => Networkprovider().networkController.stream,
            initialData: Networkprovider().initRes),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(),
        initialRoute: Welcome.id,
        routes: {
          Welcome.id: (context) => Welcome(),
          NavigatorPage.id: (context) => const NavigatorPage(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

NetworkProvider.dart

```
class Networkprovider extends ChangeNotifier {
  late StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> _subscription;
  late StreamController<ConnectivityResult> _networkController;
  late ConnectivityResult initRes = ConnectivityResult.none;

  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> get subscription => _subscription;
  StreamController<ConnectivityResult> get networkController =>
      _networkController;

  Networkprovider() {
    startup();
  }

  void startup() {
    _networkController = StreamController<ConnectivityResult>();
    networkStatusChangeListener();
  }

  void networkStatusChangeListener() async {
    _networkController.sink.add(await Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    _subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((event) {
      _networkController.sink.add(event);
    });
  }

  void disposeStreams() {
    _subscription.cancel();
    _networkController.close();
  }
}
```

Welcome.dart

```
class Welcome extends StatelessWidget {
  static String id = "welcome_screen";
  const Welcome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var res = Provider.of<Networkprovider>(context);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: MAIN_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
        body: SizedBox.expand(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: const <Widget>[
                    Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/Magnet_logo.png"))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child:
                    Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/Mannify_logo.png")),
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Spinner(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `ChangeNotifierProvider` like this

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Networkprovider()),
  ],
  child: <your widget>,
)
```

then access like this

```
final provider = Provider.of<Networkprovider>(context);
```

Comment: Thanks a  lot! This worked. But I have a doubt that in most of the StreamProvider types, we use StreamProvider instead of ChangeNotifierProvider. But everytime I used StreamProvider there seemed to show the above error .